# Forwarding adfs login to Dynamics AX

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I've created a new asp.net web application where I authenticate using adfs. I am then using this web application to talk to Dynamics AX.
Inside Dynamics Ax I've created classes and services and published them as "inbound ports" inside Dynamics AX to IIS. 
I can add a service reference inside Visual Studio to the published service (through https and require domain credentials to use).
The Service Reference works fine and I can talk to Dynamics AX with my application using the following:

```
ServiceTestClient client = new ServiceTestClient();
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = @"domain\user";
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = @"password";
```

Everything works just fine like this, I can read and write to/from AX.
But I would of course like to use the credentials I have already entered when I logged into the application through the adfs.
But my problem is that I don't really know how to do that. How can I forward the claims or tokens I've obtained to Dynamics AX?

I'm pretty sure I have to change the binding  and clientCredentialtype I'm currently using inside AX.
Once I add a service reference inside Visual Studio I get the following inside web.config:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="serviceEndpoint">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" /> 
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ServiceTest">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

So the question is, what type of binding and clientcredentialtype should I be using inside AX?
And how do I add the adfs token/credentials to the client I create?
Perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding what to do, if so I'll happily accept pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever needs an answer, I created an intermediate user in AD/DAX which has the rights to talk to the https binding, but has no access into DAX. I then set the call context to the user obtained from the adfs token.

So the intermediate user's / pass is stored in web.config and the user which authenticates through adfs is the one performing actions inside Dax.